# Is there a computer program that we could create which would, with 10-minute daily use, accelerate our ability to master the skill of philosophizing?

Tags: metaphilosophy

This summer I built [this study aid](https://nsc9.github.io/) for myself and STEM students to generate math problems so I can drill the art of problem solving with pen and paper. I don't see why there couldn't be a linguistically-fluent and artificially intelligent agent that generates philosophical problems to users to solve by hand. The agent could generate its own solution so the student can compare answers.

Going off [the Merriam-Webster definition of philosophy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philosophy):

> "a theory underlying or regarding a sphere of activity or thought"

Maybe a computer program could generate potential and relevant activities or thoughts. Then the user of the program can then write their own responsive theory underlying or regarding to the generated example of an activity or thought. The agent could also generate its own answer so the student can compare answers.

Comment: "Define the universe. Give three examples." http://www.mit.edu/people/dmredish/wwwMLRF/links/Humor/The_Exam.html

Comment: I am no expert about text generation AI but my biggest concern would be that it would generate mostly word salad (something humans, whose texts it would train from, notoriously excel at already). One very useful thing a program could do though is mining philosophy books and articles to find the authors relevant to a given topic.

Comment: The idea goes back to [Ramon Llull's "thinking machine"](https://dangerousminds.net/comments/the_13th_century_thinking_machine_of_ramon_llull), Leibniz called it [*calculus ratiocinator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_ratiocinator). For a modern incarnation see SEP:"[Computational philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-philosophy/) is the use of mechanized computational techniques to instantiate, extend, and amplify philosophical research."

Comment: Not sure whether able to accelerate philosophizing skill by 10-minute daily use of such a program you described, but if your AI program can answer the question in this site successfully to the OP questioner's satisfaction then it certainly will be able to...

Comment: Kant once hinted some insight in his Critique of Practical Reason: *...But there is no danger of this. This would be the same thing as if one sought to prove by reason that there is no reason...* Thus one particular base problem your AI philosopher/program can benchmark against is to see if it can derive such conclusion which uses reasoning (a set of logic system) to argue against the existence of itself...

Comment: I wonder what would be the design flaw in a system that would cause word salads. For designing my math problem generator that is limited to 3 different functions, the task the computer does is pseudo-randomly combine 1-3 functions with the four basic operations of arithmetic. No matter what the combination is, like [f(x)+g(x)]/h(x), it is still readable and solvable to a human and not a word salad. But if I took 28 letters and randomly permeated them into words and further permeated those words into sentences, why is this a word salad and not something of value to be studied and pondered on?

Comment: Found this to be kind of interesting and maybe on-topic. https://twitter.com/realSharonZhou/status/1583869609244905474?s=20&t=Tfnx8dig9-Fa6I5V2s-Y0w https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.11416.pdf